# How to get the most liked users on a particular date in django

Tags: python, sql, django, database, django-rest-framework

So I have a social media app, where users can like the posts of other users. Now I fetch the top 20 users who have received the most number of likes. Everything is perfect. But the problem is I cant figure out , how I can fetch the top users who have received the most likes on a particular date, for example get the top users who received most likes only today

**My LIKES MODEL**

```
class PostLike(models.Model):
    user_who_liked = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_liked = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    liked_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**SIMPLIFIED POST MODEL**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='author')
    caption = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, blank=True, through=PostLike)
    image = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
```

**SIMPLIFIED USER MODEL**

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    profile_picture = models.TextField(
        default="https://www.kindpng.com/picc/m/24-248253_user-profile-default-image-png-clipart-png-download.png")
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    objects = CustomManger()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name
```

** My query to get the top users who received the most number of likes **

```
users = User.objects.annotate(num__liked=Count('author__likes')).order_by('-num__likes')[:20]

# So everything is perfect and I am getting the users, now I dont know how to get the top users with most likes on a PARTICULAR DATE, for example today
```

** My try to get the top users with most likes on a particular day**

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
from django.utils.timezone import datetime

users = User.objects.annotate(num__liked=Count('author__likes',filter=Q(author__likes__liked_on = datetime.today()))).order_by('-num__likes')[:20]
```

But with the above query , I cant achieve it. I am getting the error:
***Related Field got invalid lookup: liked_on***

I am pretty sure, I am doing something wrong with the many-many fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Q(author__likes__liked_on = datetime.today())` won't work, because `liked_on` is a datetime, while `datetime.today()` is a date.  And the filtered field is on the 'through' table.

So you need to cast `liked_on` to a date, and look up the field on `postlike` (lower-cased by default):

`Q(author__postlike__liked_on__date = datetime.today()))`

Comment: I am still getting the error "Related Field got invalid lookup: liked_on". I think, I am doing something wrong with the many-to-many field lookup

Comment: Ah, good point.  Updated to show filtering on the 'through' table.  By default, django allows you to access a through table with the lower case of the model's name.

Comment: Thank you it works, but the problem is, now I am getting the top users in a particular date, but also the other users are showing up in the list. For example john and smith got the most likes today, and they are showing up at the top, but also the other registered users are showing up in the list. Is there a way, I can fix this

Comment: Isn't that the point of the [:20] you have on the end?

Comment: no for example I mean the users who did not receive any likes today, but still they are showing up at the bottom of the list

Comment: Oh, I see.  Add another filter: .filter(num__liked__gt=0)  Not sure if the double underscore in num__liked will cause a problem, but it'd be more consistent if named num_liked

Comment: thank you soooo much for the help, this was just perfect. Works like a charm. Could you also maybe explain me, what it does, the num__liked__gt=0

Comment: You've added a new column (num__liked) which counts the number of likes for each user.  That filter says that that number must be greater than zero, thus filtering out anyone with 0 likes.